# What is wrong with my PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I built an Oracle database (version 9.2, I know it is obsolete, but it is the version installed at my university and I do not have a choice) with a list of users and their immediate friends. I am working on a set of queries to list the "network" of a user, including his friends' friends, and to compute the degree of separation between the user in question and the other members.

I tested the three queries separately and I confirm they do work.

I would now like to create a PL/SQL procedure to combine the 3 queries, so as to be able to feed the ID of a player as a parameter, but also to launch the three queries with one Execute statement.

However, I am unable to run the procedure. I am not even able to convert the first query in a procedure (see my code below).

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Here are the queries (they are working):

```
INSERT INTO UserFriendsCopy
SELECT *
FROM UserFriends
WHERE PlayerID < FriendsWith;

INSERT INTO Degrees_Separation
   SELECT PlayerID, FriendsWith, LEVEL AS Degree
      FROM UserFriendsCopy
      START WITH PlayerID = 1
      CONNECT BY PRIOR FriendsWith = PlayerID;

SELECT FriendsWith, MIN(Degree)
FROM Degrees_Separation
GROUP BY FriendsWith;
```

Here is a procedure that I wrote to replace the first query. It is not working. Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procDegrees1
AS
DECLARE
    CURSOR UserFriendsNoDupl IS SELECT * FROM UserFriends WHERE PlayerID < FriendsWith;
BEGIN
    FOR record IN UserFriendsNoDupl
LOOP
    EXIT WHEN UserFriendsNoDupl%NOTFOUND;
    INSERT INTO UserFriendsCopy VALUES(record.PlayerID, record.FriendsWith);
END LOOP;
END;/

EXECUTE procDegrees1/
```

[UPDATE] I have re-written the procedure as follows, to take into account the comments received so far. Still, it does not work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procDegrees1
AS
BEGIN
FOR record IN (SELECT * FROM UserFriends WHERE PlayerID < FriendsWith)
LOOP
    INSERT INTO UserFriendsCopy(PlayerID,FriendsWith) VALUES(record.PlayerID, record.FriendsWith);
END LOOP;
END;/
```

By the way, here are the tables definitions, along with some dummy records:

```
DROP TABLE Degrees_Separation;
DROP TABLE UserFriends;
DROP TABLE UserFriendsCopy;

CREATE TABLE UserFriends (
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
    FriendsWith INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkUserFriends
        PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID, FriendsWith),
    CONSTRAINT fkPlayerIDThird
        FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID)
        REFERENCES Player (PlayerID),
    CONSTRAINT fkPlayerIDFourth
        FOREIGN KEY (FriendsWith)
        REFERENCES Player (PlayerID)
);

CREATE TABLE UserFriendsCopy (
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
    FriendsWith INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkUserFriendsBis
        PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (1, 2);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (2, 1);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (2, 3);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (3, 2);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (2, 4);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (4, 2);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (1, 4);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (4, 1);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (5, 6);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (6, 5);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (3, 8);

INSERT INTO UserFriends (PlayerID, FriendsWith)
VALUES (8, 3);


CREATE TABLE Degrees_Separation (
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
    FriendsWith INT NOT NULL,
    Degree INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkPlayerIDSeventh
        FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID)
        REFERENCES Player (PlayerID),
    CONSTRAINT fkPlayerIDEighth
        FOREIGN KEY (FriendsWith)
        REFERENCES Player (PlayerID)
);
```

Thanks, LC

Comment: try INSERT INTO UserFriendsCopy(PlayerID,FriendsWith) VALUES(record.PlayerID, record.FriendsWith);

Comment: Andre, thank you for your comment. I modified my code accordingly, but I still get the same error message (Error ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement).

Comment: because the keyword 'DECLARE "is not used in PL / SQL procedure, it is used in an anonymous block

Comment: @Andre, thanks. I have re-written the procedure to remove the DECLARE statement, to no avail (see newer version above).

Comment: I tried on Oracle XE 11g, it's work, maybe delete '/' after 'END;'. Show screen.

Comment: Are you getting the ORA-00900 from the procedure creation, or the execution?

Comment: @Alex: I get the error at execution of procDegrees1.

Comment: @Andre: I have set "/" as the statement separator in Squirrel. Still, I replaced "END;/" with "END;" as well as "END/", but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQL*Plus reference says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663):

> SQL*Plus treats PL/SQL subprograms in the same manner as SQL commands, except that a semicolon (;) or a blank line does not terminate and execute a block. Terminate PL/SQL subprograms by entering a period (.) by itself on a new line. You can also terminate and execute a PL/SQL subprogram by entering a slash (/) by itself on a new line.

You are putting the slash on the same line as the `end;`, which isn't valid. You need to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procDegrees1
AS
BEGIN
  FOR record IN (SELECT * FROM UserFriends WHERE PlayerID < FriendsWith)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO UserFriendsCopy(PlayerID,FriendsWith)
    VALUES(record.PlayerID, record.FriendsWith);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When you call it with `execute` you should end with a semicolon, not a slash:

```
EXECUTE procDegrees1;
```

This is an SQL*Plus shorthand for an anonymous block, and what you have after the `execute` becomes the single statement within an anonymous block, so it's expanded for actual execution and is the same as doing this:

```
BEGIN
  procDegrees1;
END;
/
```

You can see that if the statement itself causes an error. But it's important to note that `execute` this is not a SQL statement, it is a *client* command. SQL*Plus and SQL Developer recognise it, but other clients may not.

I started this answer before you mentioned in a comment that you were using Squirrel. I don't know if Squirrel allows `execute`, but the error you're getting suggests not. If it doesn't then you'll need to use the expanded anonymous block form, which should work anywhere.

---

Google [suggests](http://dbaspot.com/oracle-tools/128624-how-execute-oracle-stored-procedures-within-squirrel-sql.html) that `execute` isn't supported but you might be able to do this:

```
CALL procDegrees1
```

... but I have no idea if that's actually true...

Comment: Thanks! The execution works after I replace EXECUTE with a BEGIN / END block.